# How to get the values from JSON in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

How to get the values from JSON in javascript following is my code

```
var obj={"0.5":0.009333, "0.21":0.048667,"0.31":0.070667};
    var value =0.21;
    var p=0;
    for(i=0; i<= obj.length ;i++){
    if(value== obj[i]){                         
           p = obj[i];                   //here i want p=0.048667
           console.log("psr is :"+p);
        }
    }
```

Comment: what code you have tried tell me???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

obj.length is not supported in Javascript. You will have to loop over it using

```
for(var index in object) {
    var p = object[index];
    console.log(p);
}
```

But of course if you already know your key, then

```
console.log(object[key]);
```

is the way to go. The complete code becomes

```
var obj = {"0.5":0.009333, "0.21":0.048667,"0.31":0.070667};
var value = "0.21";
var p = obj[value];
console.log(p);
```

Comment: calculating length of JSON is possible .I want to compare given value with json key and retrieve that value corresponding to value

Comment: So you know the key and want to retrieve the corresponding value. Then use my second solution, it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Erm... won't just `obj[value]` do the trick? )

Comment: +1 : I deleted my answer, I didn't noticed he was looking values by key